# Bun install asking for password when using git+ssh url

Tags: npm, bun

I've a package in my package.json like

`"mypack": "git+ssh://git@github.com/company/mypack.git#main"`

`npm install` can use ssh and install the dependencies using ssh auth but trying to switch to bun.

`bun install` command is asking for password.

Comment: There seems to be an open issue about this: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/5027